# GitHub avatar is displayed, link to user isn't

Tags: github

I have a series of commits, most of which display a user avatar:
https://github.com/larsbrinkhoff/test/commits/test

However, most of them have no link to the GitHub user profile.  Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there is no GitHub user with that email address, but there is a Gravatar image for that address.